# Rsync: Excluding all files but no directories

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I would like to **define an rsync include/exclude rule which excludes all files in directory but includes all subdirectories inside without any files in those directories**.

Why would one want to do that?

I'm using **rsync to back up** certain Linux/Unix **systems** and if I restore one of these backups the system **won't be useable without the appropriate directories**.

A fair example would be /var/log. Obviously I don't want to include any logfiles in the backup. Nonetheless I need the directories below /var/log, e.g. /var/log/apache2 to exist or my services (apache2 in this case) won't be able to start afterwards.

It is possible to do, I did it once only with special crafted rsync exclude/include rules but right now I can't remember and since none of the rsync questions I've found on StackOverflow really provides a proper solution I though it wouldn't hurt to have this question here.

Comment: That's because SO isn't really the place for rsync questions...

Comment: There is nothing appropriate on SV either and the problem is part of an backup application I'm developing so I don't think it's entirely wrong here either.

Comment: Do you mean only copy the directory hierarchy but not the files? Here is a post that may help. http://psung.blogspot.hk/2008/05/copying-directory-trees-with-rsync.html